# Creating polygon grid in ArcGIS model using ET Geowizard?

Tags: arcgis-desktop, modelbuilder, arcgis-license-manager, error-000824, et-geowizards

When bring in the vector grid extent tool from ET Geowizards surface tools into a model An error pops up:

> ERROR 00824 The tool is not licensed

Outside of the model the tool works fine. What I need is a grid of 100 x 100 m polygons which covers the extent of another layer.

Comment: What is wrong with fish net? Why use something else?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use the **'Grid Index Features'** tool from the ArcGIS toolbox.  This tool is available for all license levels.  You can specify an input feature to base the grid on, and you can specify the grid size and units:

[image]

http://desktop.arcgis.com/en/arcmap/10.3/map/page-layouts/creating-grid-index-features.htm

---

I doubt that an ETgeo tool will run in modelbuilder, since it's 3rd party.  However, you may be able to incorporate it into a python script but I have not tried.

Answer (score 2):

You need to use is Create Fishnet Tool which is available in all licenses, and it is located under `Data management Tools -> Feature Class -> Create Fishnet`. You can specify the cell size width and height of 100 m each, and you can use it in model builder since it is part of ArcGIS Toolbox.

Check the details on how to use [Create Fishnet](http://desktop.arcgis.com/en/arcmap/10.3/tools/data-management-toolbox/create-fishnet.htm) from ArcGIS help.